# xdvipdfmx:warning: Creating ToUnicode CMap failed for FontAwesome5*.otf

Tags: xetex, miktex, latexmk, fontawesome

I am on latest miktex version with all packages (used by my latex file) installed automatically by miktex during building the project.
Building my latex file (which uses fontawesome5) using latexmk gives warnings -

```
xdvipdfmx:warning: Creating ToUnicode CMap failed for "[...]/tex/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome5/FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf"
xdvipdfmx:warning: Failed to load ToUnicode CMap for font "FontAwesome5Free-Solid"
xdvipdfmx:warning: Creating ToUnicode CMap failed for "[...]/tex/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome5/FontAwesome5Brands-Regular-400.otf"
xdvipdfmx:warning: Failed to load ToUnicode CMap for font "FontAwesome5Brands-Regular"
```

The generated pdf file looks fine as far as I can tell though.

Comment: @marcel-krüger, do you know if this is related to your fontawesome5 package or something else.

Comment: The @ syntax only works if you use the exact username, so @MarcelKrüger instead of @ marcel-krüger. Also you can not ping me if I haven't already commented the question, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work for details.

Comment: Anyway, your questions would be easier to answer if you would add a MWE, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). So in this case, a minimal document causing this warning would help analyzing the issue. Especially because the warning only seem to appear with special settings.

Comment: But to the actual point, the warning can probably be ignored: XeTeX can not create a "ToUnicode CMap". That is the mapping from glyphs to Unicode codepoints, which is necessary for reliable Copy&Paste to work. But Copy&Paste isn't really useful for icons in the first place, so as an icon font, Font Awesome doesn't need a ToUnicode CMap. If you still want one, you probably have to create it manually. Or you could use LuaLaTeX: There a CMap is generated, no warning appears and especially Font Awesome Pro loads much faster.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Also just running `xelatex file.tex` has no issues, but only `latexmk -xelatex file.tex` has it.